# How to get sql query as output as in this pic

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

How to get Query statment as output?

If i pass this statment in php

```
$studentTableUpdater= DB::table($session)
    ->where("rollNo", '=', $rollNo, 'AND', "name", '=', $name)
    ->update(['roomNo' => $migrateRoom]);
```

i could get the output statement as  "0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0031 seconds.)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable query log, e.g.:

```php
DB::enableQueryLog();
$studentTableUpdater = DB::table($session)
    ->where("rollNo", '=', $rollNo, 'AND', "name", '=', $name)
    ->update(['roomNo' => $migrateRoom]);
$query = DB::getQueryLog());
dd($query)
```